# Dualshock 4 controller not working correctly on pc

Tags: windows-10, drivers, game-controller

My pc is suddenly refusing to work with my controller.

I am using a wired dualshock 4 controller with a computer running Windows 10. When I connect the controller it appears in the device manager, but it doesn't actually work.

For some reason, the ONLY program where the controller works is InputMapper. The controller also works if I use InputMapper to simulate an Xbox controller, but this gives me immense input lag.

I have tried deleting multiple drivers, but whenever I plug the DS4 back in, the same drivers return and report that everything is working correctly. Both of my two controllers don't work.

What else is there for me to try?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! Some program called HIDGuardian was messing everything up. Here's how I fixed it:

1. Plug your controller into your pc.
2. Open the Device Manager and look for HID-Compliant Game Controller.
3. Double-click it and navigate to the Details tab, open the dropdown-menu and select Hardware-id's.
4. Copy the upper three id's or take a screenshot -- you just need to remember what they're called.
5. Open the registry editor (Windows + R -> "regedit").
6. Navigate to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HidGuardian\Parameters (if you have it).
7. Open the AffectedDevices registry and check if the hardware-id's from earlier are present in the list. If they are, remove them. Restart your computer afterwards.

After this I plugged my DS4 in and it worked just like it should.

Answer (score 0):

First, look for controller support in the application. I'm assuming you already have, but it never hurts.
Using Xpadder is a way I have gotten past this issue. Using Xpadder, I mapped every controller button to a keyboard key, and it works with minimal lag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly this program could not recognize my controller, so I wasn't able to get any further than that.